# how to add image validation in php like Size and weight

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I Want to insert an image with validation like Size and Weight if wrong size and weight than show error massage  in PHP Please help me...

**PHP script here...**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $extension = explode('.', $_FILES['image']['name']);
    $origname = $extension[0];
    $image = $origname . '-' . rand(10000, 99999) . '.' . $extension[1];
    $file_loc = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $folder = "../image/banner/";
    move_uploaded_file($file_loc, $folder . $image);
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "insert into banner(image) VALUES('$image')");
    $_SESSION['msg'] = " Successfully Added your banner Thank you!!";
}
```

Comment: please edit my code and share with me add size and weight validatiion i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                $fileinfo = @getimagesize($_FILES["file-input"]["tmp_name"]);
                $width = $fileinfo[0];
                $height = $fileinfo[1];
                $fileName = $_FILES['image']['name'];
                $explode = explode(".", $fileName);
                $origname = $explode[0];
                $image = $origname . '-' . rand(10000, 99999) . '.' . end($explode);
                $file_loc = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
                if (($_FILES["file-input"]["size"] > 2000000)) {
                    $response = array(
                        "type" => "error",
                        "message" => "Image size exceeds 2MB"
                    );
                } else if ($width > "300" || $height > "200") {
                    $response = array(
                        "type" => "error",
                        "message" => "Image dimension should be within 300X200"
                    );
                } else {
                    $folder = "../image/banner/";
                    move_uploaded_file($file_loc, $folder . $image);
                    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "insert into banner(image) VALUES('$image')");
                    $_SESSION['msg'] = " Successfully Added your banner Thank you!!";
                }
            }
```

Comment: you want random name for image?

Comment: yes sir i have need only size validation please edit my code and share with me its possible

Comment: please sir arrange my php script than share with me

Comment: insert image any size and any weight not show error

Comment: <?php if(isset($_GET['error']) && $_GET['error'] == 'size') {
    echo "mage size exceeds 2MB";
} elseif(isset($_GET['error']) && $_GET['error'] == 'width') {
    echo "Image dimension should be within 300X200";
} ?>
<form action="saveFile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
<input name="ufile" type="file" id="ufile" size="35" />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Upload" />
</form>

place of $response use this code
if (($_FILES["ufile"]["size"] > 2000000)) {
    header('location:fileUpload.php?error=size');
}

Answer (score 0):

What exact you want to find out width and size check this. If wrong please let me correct.
    For Width :

```
$fileinfo = @getimagesize($_FILES["file-input"]["tmp_name"]);
$width = $fileinfo[0];
$height = $fileinfo[1];

//For Size (in bytes)

if (($_FILES["file-input"]["size"] > 2000000)) {
        $response = array(
            "type" => "error",
            "message" => "Image size exceeds 2MB"
        );
    }
```

**may i arrange this type of php code ?**

```
$fileinfo = @getimagesize($_FILES["file-input"]["tmp_name"]);
           $width = $fileinfo[0];
           $height = $fileinfo[1];

          //For Size (in bytes)

         if (($_FILES["file-input"]["size"] > 2000000)) {
        $response = array(
            "type" => "error",
            "message" => "Image size exceeds 2MB"
            );
        } 
        $extension = explode('.', $_FILES['image'] ['name']);
        $origname= $extension[0];
        $image = $origname . '-' .rand(10000,99999) . '.' . $extension[1];
        $file_loc = $_FILES['image'] ['tmp_name'];
        $folder="../image/banner/";
         move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$image);
```

Comment: hello any body help me sir

Comment: what exactly you want for find width and size above code is there

Comment: i want to add in php code size validation like (200*100)  sir its possible

Answer (score 0):

```
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
  echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}
```

and to get height and width u can do like this way

```
$data = getimagesize($filename);
$width = $data[0];
$height = $data[1];
```

and by $width and $height u can do what is necessary